# Grid Row Height in Preview Pane in Dynamics Ax

Tags: grid, axapta, preview, dynamics-ax-2012, pane

I built a form and embedded a preview pane in it. The preview pane displays the grid populated with the data from the data source. The problem is that the row height is abnormal. It is appearing 3 times the normal height of the grid rows. I am using Dynamics Ax 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you displaying an address, street name or similar?

Grids with a string field of an extended data type with a `DisplayHeight` property of 2 or more make the row height larger to accommodate the field. You can change the property on the `FormStringControl` as well.

The solution might be to change the `DisplayHeight` back to 1 on the control.

Comment: Actually, the problem I am getting is in the preview pane. There is not problem when I just create a grid in a form. The problem is arises only when I try to display preview pane in the Grid mode by selecting "Repeating" property as "Yes".

Comment: Try to adhere to standards by running the "Check form style best practices" in the Add-Ins menu.